# How do I use a shell script to tell if a postgres database table exists

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, docker, dockerfile

I need to use entrypoint to determine whether the database is available and whether a table exists.

I use the following shell to determine if a table exists

**Part of the dockerfile content**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash","docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Shell script content**

```
until PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -h "db" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

# Prepare variables
TABLE=web_user
SQL_EXISTS=$(printf '\dt "%s"' "$TABLE")

# Credentials
USERNAME=postgres
PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE=postgres

echo "Checking if table <$TABLE> exists ..."

# Check if table exists
PGPASSWORD="$PASSWORD" psql -h "db" -U $USERNAME -d $DATABASE -c "$SQL_EXISTS"
# using #!/bin/bash
if [[ $(PGPASSWORD="$PASSWORD" psql -h "db" -U $USERNAME -d $DATABASE -c "$SQL_EXISTS") ]]
then
    echo "Table exists ..."

else
    echo "Table not exists ..., init database"
    python3 manage.py makemigrations web
    python3 manage.py migrate
fi
```

> `db` is the `service name` of the postgres container in compose

What I want is for the container to start for the first time, determine that the user table does not exist, then `create a new database`, and then restart the container to find that the user table already exists `without creating a new data table`

But when I use it on a Ubuntu16.04 base image, it simply outputs `table exists...` the first time the container starts

```
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
Checking if table <web_user> exists ...
No matching relations found.
Table exists ...
```

But what I expect is to print`table not exists..., the init database` and subsequent commands

The output using the `python alpine` base image is as follows

```
Checking if table <web_user> exists ...
Did not find any relation named ""web_user"".
Table not exists ..., init database
Migrations for 'web':
```

The difference is as follows:
`No matching relations found.` is based on the output of the `ubuntu image`,
 `Did not find any relation named ""web_user"".` based on the output of the `python:3.6.9-alpine image`

Why isn't it the else part that goes?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me why did this error occur and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that the if statement is true because you successfully connect to the db (and has nothing to do whether that connection finds the string or not)

like try this:

```
if [[ $(PGPASSWORD="$PASSWORD" psql -h "db" -U $USERNAME -d $DATABASE) ]]
then
  echo connection successful
  echo basing your previous if on:
  echo $(PGPASSWORD="$PASSWORD" psql -h "db" -U $USERNAME -d $DATABASE -c "$SQL_EXISTS")
fi
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried the section you wrote, but it doesn't seem to go into the `then section`

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this problem by changing the `base image` from `ubuntu16.04` to `ubuntu 18.04`. But I don't know what causes this.